# "Directory does not exist: /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/0.9.0/x64/bin"error in Azure DevOps and Azure App service

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-appservice

I have scheduled a release in Azure Devops Three times build is failed with error and after third time again build is done successfully but deployment is failed with below error

Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details

Anyone please help me to find the problem

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please consider including details in how you're deploying the web package as well the relevant parts of the logs.  It's nigh impossible to help you without pertinent information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure YAML Deployment failing with "Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Conflict (CODE: 409)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741421/azure-yaml-deployment-failing-with-error-failed-to-deploy-web-package-to-app-s)

Comment: @ewong  I was deploying web packages using Azure Pipelines

Comment: Failed to download "8217eacb-f9c8-47de-8008-3ff83c4bf542" from "https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.9.0/node-v0.9.0-linux-x64.tar.gz". Code(404) Message(Not Found)

Comment: Failed to download "/home/vsts/work/_temp/temp_250830773/node.exe" from "https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.9.0/win-x64/node.exe". Code(404) Message(Not Found)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT  
That is other issue , That is syntax error . But in my case three times build fail and after that build is successful and deployment is failed.